# CLLocationManager not giving me my location

Tags: iphone, mapkit

Here is my code

```
CLLocationManager* locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc]init]autorelease];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


NSLog(@"Latitude :%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude);

CLLocation* currentLocation = [locationManager location];
_drivingReverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:[currentLocation coordinate]];
[_drivingReverseGeocoder setDelegate:self];
[_drivingReverseGeocoder start];
```

When I do my NSLog my long and lat are 0.000000. Also, I am using the simulator but I expected my long and lat to be at infinite loop where my current location is. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Are you using the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`?

Comment: Yes I am am i not implementing it correctly? If your using the simulator does it always say 0.0 for everyone?

Answer (score 2):

Remove everything after startUpdatingLocation and implement this method in your class, which is part of the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol:

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    // use newLocation here
}

Also, test on an actual device.

Comment: That method will never get called though since I am using the simulator and not moving.

Comment: Yes, that's why you need to test on a device. If you haven't got a device you can simulate updates with FTLocationSimulator (https://github.com/futuretap/FTLocationSimulator) or similar solutions.